# How to play videos from mysqli database base on visibility?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have some videos on my database and I have been able to fetch them to my web page but I am trying to play this videos base on their visibility but only one of them keep playing.

Here is my code

```
<?php
    $q2="SELECT * FROM `video` limit 4" ;
   $r2= mysqli_query($con, $q2) ; 
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r2)){
    $vid = $row['video'];   
       
  
       
       ?>
<video id="myvideo"  style="width:100%; height:400px;"  controls   />
 <source  style="width:100%; height:400px;" src="video/<?php echo $vid ; ?>"  />
 </video>
     <?php } ?>

<script>
let options = {
    root:  null,
    rootmargin:'0px',
    threshold:1.0
};
    let myback = (entries, observer)=>{
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if(entry.target.id == 'myvideo'){
            if(entry.isIntersecting){
            entry.target.play();    
            }else{
            entry.target.pause();   
            }
        }
    });
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(myback, options);
observer.observe(document.querySelector('#myvideo'));
</script>
```

Comment: You're outputting multiple `<video id="myvideo">` tags. IDs in HTML must be unique. So you must generate a unique ID for each tag, and refer to it wherever you refer to `#myvideo` or `'myvideo'`. Also, this question has little to do with SQL, even though that is where you are storing your videos.

Comment: protip: autoformat your code. Your indentations make things needlessly hard to read.